# Is a function measurable if it depends on a random variable?

Tags: probability, probability-theory, measure-theory

Suppose I have a function $g$ that depends on a random variable $Y$. In this case, it might look like $g(x,Y)= xY^2$ where $x$ is just a dummy variable. In this case, is $g$ measurable?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The function itself is $g(x,y) = xy^2$.  Yes, this is measurable.  You happen to be taking that function of the random variable $Y$.

Comment: What about the case where you take some random $Y$ for each $x$  in domain? So it's kinda $g(x,Y(X))$ case I guess